# Drop dataframe row with inconsistently occurring unknown arrow end of file character?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Simplified df from prehistoric system's .txt file via `pd.read_csv(FP, sep="|", skipinitialspace=True)`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,3,"→"], 'B': [True, False, True, np.nan]}) # inaccurate replication
   A      B
0  1   True
1  2  False
2  3   True
3  ÔåÆ    NaN  # A3 displays as "→" in console
```

The "→" looking character is unknown so it's not accurately replicated here, but pandas prints "→" to console. In notepad it shows as  "", but in another system it looks like "→|". Couldn't find on [wikipedia's page on arrow symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrow_(symbol)).

The character arrives in first col of last row but inconsistently, so `read_csv`'s `skipfooter=1` isn't appropriate. I want to drop the row when the char appears but `df.iat[-1,0] == "→"` returns False and I can't pin down what this character is.

How can I do this? Find the value by printing character code (whatever that is)?

Comment: Are rest of the characters in column  `A`  except  `"→"`  numeric?

Comment: No, unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how to replicate the issue but this work fine for me:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,3,"→"], 'B': [True, False, True, np.nan]})
df = df[df['A'] != u'→']
```

Or use the unicode escape sequence like this:

```
df = df[df['A'] != u'\u2192']
```

Output:

```
    A   B
0   1   True
1   2   False
2   3   True
```

Now coming back to your code, you can use:

```
df.iat[-1,0] == u"\u2192"
>>> True
```

Answer (score 1):

Eventually found `df.iat[-1,0] == ""` (char should be within quotations) returned True, but was unsure if "" was any unknown char. This additionally checks that all other cols are na before dropping the row:

```
if df.iat[-1,0] == "":
    for colnum in range(1,len(df.columns)):
        if pd.isna(df.iloc[-1,colnum]):
            DropRow = True
        else:
            DropRow = False
            break
    if DropRow:
        df.drop(df.index[-1], inplace = True)
```

edit: the char doesn't show in submitted answer, but it should sit within empty quotations. It looks like an empty rectangle or a square with a "?" inside.